# How to rebuild Music.app library—or prevent corruption

Tags: music, metadata

*What’s the **easiest** way to fix corruption in the library of Music.app?*

In Music.app library, I had an album that showed two discs.

The last four songs on disk one could't be selected and none of the songs in disk two could be selected.  The ones that could be selected could be played.

Disk two had space at the end for five songs with no titles and durations of "-0:00" [sic].  These could not be selected.

"Not selected" = neither single- nor double-click on title nor on the empty title space had any effect.

I did "show in finder" and the directory looks reasonable.  But it contains one song without a disk number, i.e., file name starts with "09 " instead of "2-09 " and that song did not show in the app's view of the album.

I dragged the directory to my desktop and did `chmod 000` on it, then in the app's album view, select all, and delete.  All the song positions remained, but the titles disappeared, except that the first three slots changed to the first three songs on a different album, different artist, and the first slot on disk two changed to the last song on that other album.  The metadata (Get Info) on those songs was still correct.  The view of that album looked OK.

I tried File→Library→Consolidate but that did not fix it.

I also moved that (good?) album to Desktop and `chmod 000` then selected all songs (in Music), delete, and exit the Music app.  When I relaunch it, I could not find either artist in the search feature.  Then I could unlock the directories on the desktop and re-import.

I don’t want to delete and re-import the entire library, because it has five thousand tracks, and each has two items of metadata that are recorded in the library and not in the ID3 tags.  Some (purchased) have album art in the library and not in the MP3 or AAC file.

Without syncing, I checked our iPad and the two-disk album looks correct.  But the other album is missing, although the sync settings for that 256GB iPad have always been "entire library"!

I've suggested to Apple that Music.app needs something like Mail.app’s "Rebuild Mailbox."

UPDATE: This was a one-time odd event, but recently (two or three days), a similar (but not identical) corruption has been happening frequently.  A sync to iPad/iPhone will report that several songs "could not be found."  In locating them, I see that the listing in the library is unchanged, but in Finder, I see that the *filename* has been changed to add, delete, or change a disk number but the file is still in the correct directory.

It seems that the change may be happening **at the time of a sync**.  I syncd to an iPad that selects "entire music library" and got no error messages, then immediately sync’d to an iPad that had "only selected" and several songs "could not be found."  I found and located all of those in Music.app, and sync’d the same iPad again, only to get a different list.  I've reported this as a bug, but since Music still has bugs in sync that were reported before it changed its name, **I hope someone can tell me a way to make this stop.**

Comment: chmod 000 will make your data inaccessible. You better try «chmod ug+rx» or «chmod 755»

Comment: I wanted them inaccessible, because Music and other apps in macOS are sometimes able to locate their files when you move them.  After I deleted then from the app, I unlocked them (chmod 700) so that I could re-import.